# How to test an abstract class?

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd

I am confused in the way how to start testing an abstract class.

- Should I test every method?
- What should I test?
- Should I not test abstract classes?

An example:

```php
abstract class Command
{
    private $params;

    public function with(array $params = [])
    {
        $this->params = $params;
    }

    public function getParams()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }

    abstract public function run();
}
```

Should I test it like:

```php
/** @test */
public function is_an_abstract_class()
{
    $command = $this->getReflectionClass();
    $this->assertTrue($command->isAbstract());
}

/** @test */
public function has_an_run_method()
{
    $command = $this->getReflectionClass();
    $method = $this->getReflectionMethod('run');

    $this->assertTrue($command->hasMethod('run'));
    $this->assertTrue($method->isAbstract());
    $this->assertTrue($method->isPublic());
    $this->assertEquals(0, $method->getNumberOfParameters());
}
```

Comment: the abstract class doesn't have a `$params` field?

Comment: @Matteo updated.

Comment: I would just extend the abstract class by a non abstract child class. This way you can then instantiate the class and test it like you test any other class.

Comment: @user2190492 so you mean I should only focus on testing the inherited classes behavior, and stop testing the abstract class like the way I did in my question?

Comment: The class that inherits from your abstract class can literally be empty. It won't change or override any behavior in the abstract class. The child class I mean, just exists to make the abstract class instantiatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I not test abstract classes?

Under most circumstances, this would be my choice.

Reason #1: the fact that some class inherits from an abstract class is an *implementation detail*, not a *behavior*.  We don't want to couple our tests to implementation details.

Reason #2: I would expect the code in the abstract class to be covered by the tests that cover its descendants.

If you design were emerging "test first", then you already have coverage of this code, because the abstract class would be something that you would introduce to your design via refactoring a class that was already under test.